# Android: CardView inside LinearLayout makes app to crash

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-cardview, classcastexception

Given the next xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/llCommunityMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llCommunity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cvFindCollege"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#f5f5f5"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

                <com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.component.view.TMButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnSuggestImprovements"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    style="@style/button_text_default"
                    android:text="@string/activitycommunity_button_suggestimprovements" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.component.view.TMButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnFindCollege"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    style="@style/button_text_default"
                    android:text="@string/community_button_findcollege" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/llCommunityKhan"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.component.view.TMButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnKhan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    style="@style/button_text_default"
                    android:text="@string/activitykhan_title" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/footermenu_default" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

footer.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llMainMenu"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border_top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/pref_category_animations"
            android:id="@+id/btnTests"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_main_tests" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMainMenuTests"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mainmenu_button_tests"
            android:textColor="#a8a8a8"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/pref_category_animations"
            android:id="@+id/btnRecords"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_main_records" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMainMenuRecords"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mainmenu_button_records"
            android:textColor="#a8a8a8"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMainMenuImportExport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/pref_category_animations"
            android:id="@+id/btnImportExport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/button_records_importexport" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMainMenuImportExport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mainmenu_button_importexport"
            android:textColor="#a8a8a8"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMainMenuProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/pref_category_animations"
            android:id="@+id/btnProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/button_records_progress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMainMenuProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mainmenu_button_progress"
            android:textColor="#a8a8a8"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/pref_category_animations"
            android:id="@+id/btnCommunity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_main_community" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMainMenuCommunity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mainmenu_button_community"
            android:textColor="#a8a8a8"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/pref_category_animations"
            android:id="@+id/btnUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_main_user" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMainMenuUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mainmenu_button_User"
            android:textColor="#a8a8a8"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My app crashes as soon as it tries to set the layout with the following exception

```
android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

What may be wrong?

Comment: The footer is totally white in preview. And my app crashes with it. Try to run your app without the footer. Then everything should run properly. You now know where to troubleshoot. I can't without the whole content. So hope your question is solved :) Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your Layout with the stuff I have from you. I don't have the `footer` (not tested) and `Button` implementation. I replaced your `Buttons` with the default onces. What I changed; You shouldn't use a `ScrollView` for such amount of `Views` and it should be on top as a `rootView`. I replaced your `ScrollView` with a `NestedScrollView` and swapped the places with the root `RelativeLayout` (changed the parameters also):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCommunityMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llCommunity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
                    android:id="@+id/cvFindCollege"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#f5f5f5"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSuggestImprovements"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFindCollege"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:text="Button 2"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llCommunityKhan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnKhan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:text="Button 3"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Yet, if I run the app everything works fine. My guess is that the `NestedScrollView` served as a `rootView` solved the problem. If not there are only 2 things you need to check. Your `Button` implementation or the `footer`. Cheers :)

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DEX7RA. I've added footer in case it is of any help for you to continue helping me. I still cannot figure out what is going on, tried your xml to no avail, the same exception :(

Comment: Without footer it still crashes? Even you remove your <include layout footer ?

Comment: The fact is if I remove the CardView or replace it with a LinearLayout it just works fine, but I need a card view @DEX7RA

Comment: You need a RelativeLayout that surrounds the CardView. If everything works fine, then this will solve it.

Comment: I need the footer because it's the menu, but just tried to see if it works and still the same exception. I'll try your last suggestion, wrapping CardView with a RelativeLayout and let you know @DEX7RA

Comment: I updated my code. That's how it should look like with the RelativeLayout surrounding. So the footer isn't the problem I see. Just after you added the cardView everything messed up.

Comment: Surrounded the CardView by a RelativeLayout and still the same exception :(

Comment: Oke, did you remove the CardView and tried if the project runs without? It would be nice if you could send me the project to test it. I can fix it and send you back :) By the way remove xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" at the cardview and import "app:" again.

Comment: If I remove the CardView with your last code and no footer what I get is "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams". Cannot send you the code. @DEX7RA

Comment: I cannot help you anymore. Because I can run everything with my code. Seems there is something wrong in other part of the code I can't see. I understand I you don't want to share it, but then I'm unable to help you with the given information. I let my answer stay unchecked even it might be correct :D

Comment: OK @DEX7RA, I was struggling my head and I finally figured out, not sure why but the problem is my TMButton. Replacing it but an Android Button it works just fine, so I will mark your answer as correct and I appreciate your effort very much.

Comment: As I guessed :D Nice, glad to hear :) Yihaaa ;) Upvoted your question, dunno why everyone voting it down, legitim question in my opinion